# Discord.js - getting a GuildMember's displayName gives me a TypeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, typeerror

I really don't know what's going on here. My code is inside the [Akairo Framework](https://discord-akairo.github.io) but the error points in every direction to discord.js itself. Here's the error:

```
/home/runner/guard/Listeners/automod/nicknames.js:14
            if (message.member.displayName.includes(word)) {
                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of null
    at module.exports.exec (/home/runner/guard/Listeners/automod/nicknames.js:14:32)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at Client.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/runner/guard/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/runner/guard/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/runner/guard/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/runner/guard/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/runner/guard/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/runner/guard/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

This is my code: (bannedWords is an array of strings that I run through to check against the member's nickname) (it's inside a `message` event listener)

```
const bannedWords = require('./badwords.json').words;
for (const word of bannedWords) {
    if (message.member.displayName.includes(word)) {
        message.member.setNickname(`Moderated Nickname`)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bit of a logical flaw in your code: you do not check if the message was sent in DMs. If the message was indeed a DM, then `message.member` would be null (as DM channels are not part of any server), which pretty much explains your error.

You should fix this by either explicitly checking (and returning) if the channel is a DM, or if it is a falsy value

```js
//some code ...
if(!message.member) return;
for (const word of bannedWords) {
    if (message.member.displayName.includes(word)) {
        message.member.setNickname(`Moderated Nickname`)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of null

This means "message.member" is null and it cannot find the property "displayName", which then makes sense.

I think we need to see more of your code in order to figure out where it went wrong. I'm guessing you are trying to run that if statement on a member object that doesn't exist.